# Agent jobs on SSIS package failed

Tags: database, ssis, job-scheduling, system-administration, ssms-2012

I built a SSIS package and try to schedule with agent jobs. It failed with this error:

`non-sysadmins have been denied permission to run dts execution job steps without a proxy account. the step failed.`

I can not change the agent owner. I have db_owner rights on the database, and public rights on server level. 
I can’t create a proxyaccount and as I said, I can’t change the agent owner to ‘sa’.
Is there any solution to solve this?

Comment: `I have db_owner rights on the database` _which_ database? There's likely at least 5 on the box in question

Comment: Database used in the SSIS package

Comment: `Database used in the SSIS package` are we to interpret that as a custom user database and not one of the system databases? Do you have owner rights on any of the system databases?

Comment: What account is SQL Agent running under?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should ask someone with the permissions to create a proxyaccout for running SSIS packages and change the settings for job step to run as the newly created account.